# Где прописать Toolbar для AppCompatActivity и нескольких фрагментов?

Tags: android, android-fragment, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-support-library

Хочется изменить мобильное приложение и использовать [android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) вместо ActionBar, потому что в последнем трудно понять значение иконок без текста:

[image: action bar]

Вот мой нынешний layout-файл **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/root" />
```

и вот единственная **MainActivity.java**, показывающая один из нескольких фрагментов:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
                        implements MainFragment.MainListener,
                                    SettingsFragment.SettingsListener,
                                    OnBackStackChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "main")
                .commit();
        }
    }
```

**Вопрос:** куда прописывать определение Toolbar - в файл activity_main.xml (и в какое конкретно место в нем) или какой-то другой файл?

Для того, чтобы было понятно, что именно я пытаюсь поместить в Toolbar -

мое приложение использует один общий **menu.xml** с "Настройками":

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

И еще специфические файлы для каждого фрагмента - например **menu_main.xml** для MainFragment (показанного в скриншоте выше):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_swap"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_vert_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_swap"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
        android:orderInCategory="40"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_shuffle"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_recall"
        android:orderInCategory="60"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vertical_align_bottom_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_recall"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_turn"
        android:orderInCategory="80"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_turn"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, ваша цель просто поменять тулбар? Если да, то это должен быть отдельный файл .xml, который подключается к activity

Comment: Да, цель - начать использовать Toolbar вместо ActionBar. Но непонятно, где его декларировать - потому что activity_main.xml у меня пустышка, в которую SupportFragmentManager вставляет разные фрагменты. То есть если я напишу Toolbar там, то он же исчезнет при смене фрагмента

Comment: первая [ссылка](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) гугла.

Comment: Прописывете тулбар первым виджетом в разметку для активити, под ним контейнер для фрагментов и ничего никуда не исчезнет. Если вы назначите тулбар в качестве экшенбара методом `setSupportActionBar(toolbar); ` , то работать с ним можете, как с обычным экшенбаром, в том числе и замена иконок для фрагментов.

Comment: @Denis Zinkovskiy в "первой ссылке гугла" ни слова о фрагментах.

Comment: Ваш вопрос немного некорректно задан) потому как toolbar не имеет связи с фрагментами, последние вставляются в контейнер, то есть в активити, переключение/перелистывание/замена/удаление фрагментов не имеют отношению к тулбару. Вы так и не прочитали статью, которая весьма полезная, на том же сайте след [статья](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) тот же тулбар + viewpager с фрагментами. К тому же в интернете куча статей как реализовать материальный тулбар.

Comment: добавлю к ответам выше , расценивай новый тулбар как обычную вьюшку, где и как будешь использовать твое дело, хоть по середине экрана )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем Тулбар Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primary"> 
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

В  activity_main.xml добовляем

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

В MainActivity.java добовляем:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
```

и методе onCreate

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Да не забываем в import  добавить

```
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

activity_main.xml =

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java =

```
package info.fandroid.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: А где именно в activity_main.xml добавлять этот include - до, внутри или после FrameLayout?

Comment: Внутри. выше все указано. только у меня написано LinearLayout, но это как вашей душе угодно

Comment: @AlexanderFarber в той разметке, что в этом ответе, контейнер для фрагментов (`FrameLayout`) нужно поставить вместо `TextView`. Тулбар - это такой же виджет, как и все остальные - он займет то место, какое вы ему определите в разметке. Например, если вы поставите его после `TextView`, то он будет снизу .. Так же, если вы не собираетесь использовать этот же тулбар в других активити, то не обязательно выделять его в отдельную разметку, можно включить все в основную